# List package dependents in Chocolatey

Tags: chocolatey

Is there a way to list dependencies of a package?

`clist --detail -e PACKAGE_NAME` is of no help, and I can't find anything in the documentation.

Is there a way to list dependents of a package?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is not, but filing a feature request is a good way to get something like this implemented. It looks like this has already been requested here: https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/1276. Subscribe/comment on the issue.